# Convert json string to JSONObject in java

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

I have following json string response string variable

```
response  = ""[{"firstname":"test","mobileno":"1234567890"},{"firstname":"Saleha","mobileno":"9960439495"},{"firstname":"Nayan","mobileno":"9960439495"},{"firstname":"Harsheen","mobileno":"9960439495"}]""
```

after executing bellow line i got exception

```
JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(response);
```

Any solution?

Comment: What is your Exception message?

Comment: You are trying to build a JSONObject from a JSONArray format String.

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value [{ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Your code will work if you try to parse only {"firstname":"test","mobileno":"1234567890"}.

Comment: That is array of json not single josn record

Comment: If a json string starts with "[" then its an array and if it starts with "{" then only its an object. keep it as a thumb rule.

Comment: Whether you used [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)?

  Just a line of code where you can convert string to java object and java object to string.. Very Simple.

     String a= gson.toString("");
     ClassNames a= gson.fromString(response, ClassName.class); // string to object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having the array so try to get this string in JSONARRAY

```
 JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(response);
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.String)) is the reference

Answer (score 0):

Your "response" string is a JsonArray. Try below code :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse an array and not an object:

```
JSONArray myarray = new JSONArray(response);
```

You can iterate your array with a simple for.

```
for(int i = 0;i<myarray.length();i++)
{
 JSONObject obj = myarray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your json response is jsonarray,So change

```
JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(response);
```

to

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
```

and get jsonobject as

```
for(int i = 0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
 JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Comment: There is no `size` method in JSONArray

Comment: @PedroOliveira ohh ,typo